# WPF Select text + Highlight

Tags: wpf, select, textbox, syntax-highlighting, textblock

I have a **ListView** with a **Binding Property** with {get;set;} Name ( type string ) and each one is  binding in WPF textblock. 
**First requirement** be able to select a path of the text using cursor and to copy with Ctrl+C (This can be done with textBox). 
**Second requirement** is to highlight programmatically any part of Name which contains a string, and this should be able to highlight all names in that list (this can be done with textblock with inlines).

**Question:** how i can combine these two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx). It contains inlines, like TextBlock does, but it also supports highlighting and copying.